# Issues with browser compatibility and Save As action on <a href=""> click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, firefox

There is a basic difference between browsers on Windows and Linux( Ubuntu 22.04 ) operating systems.

Default behavior on Windows (clean installation) is that files are automatically downloaded in Download folder.

Default behavior on Linux ( clean installation ) is that Save As dialog is raised.
[image: Default Ubuntu 22.04 Save As Chrome]

Yes I'm aware that you can configure your browser and enable the feature on Windows operating system. But from UX perspective that is one step too many.

Is there a way to programmatically raise the Save As dialog. For instance this is a snippet that generates a link with few of the options tested:

```
download(url, downloadName) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.style.display = 'none';
    // a.download = '';
    a.download = downloadName;
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.type = 'application/unknown';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```

Best regards

Comment: There is no such way. It is purely a browser setting that's up to the user to set how they want.